# What is the best way of getting a json object tree from a parent child relation

Tags: c#, angular

Say I have a list of parent-child related folders. How can I get the following specific json object to be used by angular mat tree:

Note: the list for this will indicate Groceries and reminders are root, fruits is subfolder to groceries.

Comment: Could you please post some details? A sample json text would help

Comment: Are you missing some details? The text seems to indicate so ("the following json", "groceries", "reminders" etc). Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.newtonsoft.com/json to serialize any C# Object to JSON

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
// {
//   "Name": "Apple",
//   "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//   "Sizes": [
//     "Small"
//   ]
// }
```